# How to get currently logged in user in C++ when run as administrator in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows

GetUserName() method gives SYSTEM when it runs as administrator. How to get current logged in user name when run as administrator?

Comment: My guess is that you can't easily do this: what would happen if there are multiple users logged in?